# API to get Abandoned cart items

Tags: magento2, checkout, cart

I want to get a list of items which customers left in their shopping cart (abandoned cart) from my store using the Magento API

I can't find any API call in the below documentation, to get such list

http://devdocs.magento.com/swagger/#/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check below link,here all api is defined to get and post cart item data:

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/rest/list.html

For Quote API->
there is a list of api that you can use

```
GET    /V1/carts/:cartId
* GET    /V1/carts/search
POST   /V1/carts/
POST   /V1/customers/:customerId/carts
PUT    /V1/carts/:cartId
POST   /V1/carts/mine
GET    /V1/carts/mine
* PUT    /V1/carts/mine
PUT    /V1/carts/mine/order
GET    /V1/guest-carts/:cartId
POST   /V1/guest-carts
PUT    /V1/guest-carts/:cartId
PUT    /V1/guest-carts/:cartId/order
.....
```

You can get all type of cart items(for logged in or guest customers) by using above api.

Also you can check link,which will be useful for you.
Let me know if you need any help.